# Migrating LDAP to local authentication elytron system in Wildfly 20.0.1 Final for JavaEE8 WebApp

Tags: primefaces, wildfly, java-ee-8, jsf-2.3, elytron

Help me with the error in server.log when login in JavaEE Web App with Java 8.
Technologies Used

Netbeans IDE 12.6 and Serenity template
Java EE 8
Layered design pattern using Mobility Framework
Primefaces 11
Java Server Faces (JSF) 2.3 and Facelets language
Primeflex 3
PrimeIcons 5
Wildfly 20.01 Final
Omnifaces 3.14.4
Jasper Reports 6.20.6
iText PDF 5.5.6
Apache mobility-commons

Project Structure

packages

mobility-purchase (Java EE Modules):

mobility-purchase-war.war
mobility-purchase-ejb.jar

mobility-purchase-ejb

mobility-purchase-war

*jboss-web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <context-root>/mobility-purchase-war</context-root>
    <security-domain>
        PurchaseDm
    </security-domain>

</jboss-web>
```

**Wildfly 20.0.1 Final**
*standalone.xml* A resume for the limit of 30000 characters.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:13.0">
    <extensions>
       ...list...
    </extensions>
    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <server-identities>
                    <ssl>
                        <keystore path="application.keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="password" alias="server" key-password="password" generate-self-signed-certificate-host="localhost"/>
                    </ssl>
                </server-identities>
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="file"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <http-upgrade enabled="true"/>
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
        <access-control provider="simple">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
    </management>
    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:8.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="io.jaegertracing.Configuration">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch-jberet:2.0">
            <default-job-repository name="in-memory"/>
            <default-thread-pool name="batch"/>
            <job-repository name="in-memory">
                <in-memory/>
            </job-repository>
            <thread-pool name="batch">
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:bean-validation:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:core-management:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:6.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/MobilityPurchaseDS" pool-name="MobilityPurchaseDS">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/purchase</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>postgresql-42.2.19_org.postgresql.Driver_42_2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
                        <password>postgres</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                </datasource>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:discovery:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:distributable-web:2.0" default-session-management="default" default-single-sign-on-management="default">
            <infinispan-session-management name="default" cache-container="web" granularity="SESSION">
                <primary-owner-affinity/>
            </infinispan-session-management>
            <infinispan-single-sign-on-management name="default" cache-container="web" cache="sso"/>
            <infinispan-routing cache-container="web" cache="routing"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:5.0">
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <concurrent>
                <context-services>
                    <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
                </context-services>
                <managed-thread-factories>
                    <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
                </managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-executor-services>
                    <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="5000"/>
                </managed-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                    <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" keepalive-time="3000"/>
                </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
            </concurrent>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee-security:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:7.0">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-cpu-count" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" derive-size="from-worker-pools" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple"/>
                <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
                <data-stores>
                    <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                </data-stores>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default">
                <channel-creation-options>
                    <option name="MAX_OUTBOUND_MESSAGES" value="1234" type="remoting"/>
                </channel-creation-options>
            </remote>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="60" unit="seconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
            <default-security-domain value="other"/>
            <application-security-domains>
                <application-security-domain name="PurchaseDm" security-domain="PurchaseDm"/>
            </application-security-domains>
            <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
            <statistics enabled="${wildfly.ejb3.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
            <log-system-exceptions value="true"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:10.0" final-providers="combined-providers" disallowed-providers="OracleUcrypto">
            <providers>
                <aggregate-providers name="combined-providers">
                    <providers name="elytron"/>
                    <providers name="openssl"/>
                </aggregate-providers>
                <provider-loader name="elytron" module="org.wildfly.security.elytron"/>
                <provider-loader name="openssl" module="org.wildfly.openssl"/>
            </providers>
            <audit-logging>
                <file-audit-log name="local-audit" path="audit.log" relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" format="JSON"/>
            </audit-logging>
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="ApplicationDomain" default-realm="ApplicationRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                    <realm name="ApplicationRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                    <realm name="local"/>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="ManagementDomain" default-realm="ManagementRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
                    <realm name="ManagementRealm" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
                    <realm name="local" role-mapper="super-user-mapper"/>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="PurchaseDm" default-realm="PurchaseRealm" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper" role-decoder="groups-to-roles">
                    <realm name="PurchaseRealm"/>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="MobilityPurchaseDm" default-realm="PurchaseRealm">
                    <realm name="PurchaseRealm"/>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
            <security-realms>
                <aggregate-realm name="PurchaseRealm" authentication-realm="PurchaseGLDAP" authorization-realm="PurchaseGLDAP"/>
                <identity-realm name="local" identity="$local"/>
                </jdbc-realm>
                <jdbc-realm name="PurchaseGLDAP">
                    <principal-query sql="select tpr.role_name from th_person_roles tpr join th_person tp on (tp.user_id = tpr.user_id) where tp.email= concat(?,'@purchase')" data-source="MobilityPurchaseDS">
                        <attribute-mapping>
                            <attribute to="groups" index="1"/>
                        </attribute-mapping>
                    </principal-query>
                </jdbc-realm>
                <properties-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                    <users-properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/>
                    <groups-properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </properties-realm>
                <properties-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                    <users-properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" digest-realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                    <groups-properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </properties-realm>
            </security-realms>
            <mappers>
                <simple-permission-mapper name="default-permission-mapper" mapping-mode="first">
                    <permission-mapping>
                        <principal name="anonymous"/>
                        <permission-set name="default-permissions"/>
                    </permission-mapping>
                    <permission-mapping match-all="true">
                        <permission-set name="login-permission"/>
                        <permission-set name="default-permissions"/>
                    </permission-mapping>
                </simple-permission-mapper>
                <constant-realm-mapper name="local" realm-name="local"/>
                <simple-role-decoder name="groups-to-roles" attribute="groups"/>
                <constant-role-mapper name="super-user-mapper">
                    <role name="SuperUser"/>
                </constant-role-mapper>
            </mappers>
            <permission-sets>
                <permission-set name="login-permission">
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.security.auth.permission.LoginPermission"/>
                </permission-set>
                <permission-set name="default-permissions">
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.deployment.BatchPermission" module="org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet" target-name="*"/>
                    <permission class-name="org.wildfly.transaction.client.RemoteTransactionPermission" module="org.wildfly.transaction.client"/>
                    <permission class-name="org.jboss.ejb.client.RemoteEJBPermission" module="org.jboss.ejb-client"/>
                </permission-set>
            </permission-sets>
            <http>
                <http-authentication-factory name="management-http-authentication" security-domain="ManagementDomain" http-server-mechanism-factory="global">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST">
                            <mechanism-realm realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                        </mechanism>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </http-authentication-factory>
                <http-authentication-factory name="purchase-http-auth" security-domain="PurchaseDm" http-server-mechanism-factory="global">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="FORM">
                            <mechanism-realm realm-name="PurchaseRealm"/>
                        </mechanism>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </http-authentication-factory>
                <http-authentication-factory name="mobilitypurchase-http-auth" security-domain="MobilityPurchaseDm" http-server-mechanism-factory="global"/>
                <provider-http-server-mechanism-factory name="global"/>
            </http>
            <sasl>
                <sasl-authentication-factory name="application-sasl-authentication" sasl-server-factory="configured" security-domain="ApplicationDomain">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="JBOSS-LOCAL-USER" realm-mapper="local"/>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST-MD5">
                            <mechanism-realm realm-name="ApplicationRealm"/>
                        </mechanism>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </sasl-authentication-factory>
                <sasl-authentication-factory name="management-sasl-authentication" sasl-server-factory="configured" security-domain="ManagementDomain">
                    <mechanism-configuration>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="JBOSS-LOCAL-USER" realm-mapper="local"/>
                        <mechanism mechanism-name="DIGEST-MD5">
                            <mechanism-realm realm-name="ManagementRealm"/>
                        </mechanism>
                    </mechanism-configuration>
                </sasl-authentication-factory>
                <configurable-sasl-server-factory name="configured" sasl-server-factory="elytron">
                    <properties>
                        <property name="wildfly.sasl.local-user.default-user" value="$local"/>
                    </properties>
                </configurable-sasl-server-factory>
                <mechanism-provider-filtering-sasl-server-factory name="elytron" sasl-server-factory="global">
                    <filters>
                        <filter provider-name="WildFlyElytron"/>
                    </filters>
                </mechanism-provider-filtering-sasl-server-factory>
                <provider-sasl-server-factory name="global"/>
            </sasl>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:10.0">
            <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="passivation">
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="sso"/>
                <local-cache name="routing"/>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="server" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
                <local-cache name="default"/>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="passivation">
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" module="org.infinispan.hibernate-cache">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <object-memory size="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <object-memory size="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps"/>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:3.0">
            <worker name="default"/>
            <buffer-pool name="default"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:2.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:5.0">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
            <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:4.0">
            <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
            <mail-session name="purchasemail" jndi-name="java:/purchasemail/resource">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>

    <deployments>
        <deployment name="postgresql-42.2.19" runtime-name="postgresql-42.2.19">
            <content sha1="85cb20fe8151b6d90900d5ae5cfe0ad7c3e8f921"/>
        </deployment>
    </deployments>
</server>
```

*server.log*

```
2024-02-16 21:27:50,791 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /mobility-purchase-war/faces/access.xhtml: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.ElytronHttpServletExchange.forward(ElytronHttpServletExchange.java:128)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.HttpAuthenticator$AuthenticationExchange.forward(HttpAuthenticator.java:502)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.form.FormAuthenticationMechanism.sendPage(FormAuthenticationMechanism.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.form.FormAuthenticationMechanism.lambda$error$1(FormAuthenticationMechanism.java:188)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.HttpAuthenticator$AuthenticationExchange.authenticate(HttpAuthenticator.java:301)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.HttpAuthenticator$AuthenticationExchange.access$800(HttpAuthenticator.java:249)
    at org.wildfly.security.http.HttpAuthenticator.authenticate(HttpAuthenticator.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.ServletSecurityContextImpl.authenticate(ServletSecurityContextImpl.java:115)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:55)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.MetricsHandler.handleRequest(MetricsHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.MetricsChainHandler.handleRequest(MetricsChainHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:370)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```